# Laravel echo server killed on exit console

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-echo

i'm using laravel-echo-server and all works fine, if i launch server with this command:

```
laravel-echo-server start
```

i see:

L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.2.8

```
Starting server...

✔  Running at localhost on port 3001
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for http events...
✔  Listening for redis events...

Server ready!
```

But if i close with ctrl+c the server has been killed! the same things if i use this command:

```
laravel-echo-server start &
```

if i disconnect my ssh connection, the server stop work!

How can i launch in background mode?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) on linux. Here is a manual: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#supervisor-configuration

Here is my supervisor config file:

```
[program:websocket-server]
process_name=%(program_name)s
directory=/var/www/example.de/public_html/
command=/usr/lib/node_modules/laravel-echo-server/bin/server.js start
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/example.de/logs/websocket-server.log
```

Now you can start the server in the background with `supervisorctl start websocket-server:*`

Answer (score 9):

I recommend to use the [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) tool to manage the *larval-echo-server* service. After install **pm2** you must create a json file inside the Laravel project with a content like this:

**echo-pm2.json**

```
{
  "name": "echo",
  "script": "laravel-echo-server",
  "args": "start"
}
```

Then run the next command to start the service in background:

```
pm2 start echo-pm2.json
```

Yo can use `pm2 monit` command for real time monitoring or `pm2 logs` to get the service logs as well.

Comment: hi, this still return `net::ERR_TIMED_OUT`